# Is it possible to add the items to the CheckedListBox by typing in CheckedListBox

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have looked though the documentation for `CheckedListBox` class, but could not find if it is possible to add items to the list by directly typing the names of the items, right in the `CheckedListBox`, instead of relying on the other controls ?
Right now, in my application, user have to click "Add" button that opens another window, where user enters all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `CheckedListBox` is designed to accept text.  Short of intercepting keyboard events, I don't think you can get data typed from a keyboard from that control.

You can always make a custom control for that behavior.  One that has your `CheckedListBox` and a separate text field to add new data.  That's the best idea I've got.